# Ubuntu lag, everything stuck every 5 seconds

Tags: ubuntu, lag

I just installed Ubuntu in my Acer 4820TG yesterday but everything lags. Every 5 seconds (approximately) my mouse & keyboard sticks and the screen blinks and loops.

[Here is a video showing the behaviour.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1AG-KJJ_DqI)
[in this video I'm circling my mouse , you will see my mouse stop every 5 seconds.]

Comment: Try installing AMD's propitiatory graphics (fglrx) driver for your GPU. Go to Additional Drivers from your dash. Select "Using Video driver for the AMD graphics accelerator from fglrx (propitiatory)" and click Apply Changes. See if this helps.

Comment: I can't select "installing AMD's propitiatory graphics (fglrx) driver for your GPU" when I click apply its returning to default

Comment: Were you connected to the internet while installing the driver? You need an active internet connection as it will download the drivers from the internet and then install it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have Ubuntu Server and 2 variants of Ubuntu desktop installed on my Acer Aspire 4820TG. Server and one Desktop are 14.04 the other desktop is 15.04 and I do not have these issues. I think it may be something to do with the Intel Graphics and the Radeon video card. Try making it only use 'Descrete Graphics'.

```
-Boot up into your BIOS (f2) at startup.
-Go -> to 'Main'
-Scroll to Graphic mode and make it [Discrete].
-Save and Exit
```

This will make your graphics not switchable. This has seem to fix a lot of things for me. Even on windows switchable graphics was a huge problem for me. Cause BSOD all the time.

Comment: Work like a charm. what graphic  "Discrete" mode use [ATI or Intel]?

Comment: Discrete uses the ATI graphics card. Hence you may suffer from battery drainage.

Answer (score 1):

A little late for the party. I know that the answer above is already accepted, but I want to share my experience which might be helpful for others. The problem was something to do with ACPI. I wrote a  [**bash script**](https://github.com/Obadah-H/Fix-video-lag-in-linux) which solves this problem automatically:

```bsh
if grep -q acpi_rev_override "/etc/default/grub"; then
 echo 'Found settings entry, nothing changed';
else
 sudo sed -i 's/splash/splash acpi_rev_override=1/g' /etc/default/grub
 echo "Finished successfully. please reboot to apply the new settings"
fi
```

I'm also posting a reverse script in case it is needed:

```bsh
if grep -q acpi_rev_override=1 "/etc/default/grub"; then
 sudo sed -i 's/splash acpi_rev_override=1/splash/g' /etc/default/grub
 echo "Reset finished successfully"
else
 echo 'No settings found, exiting.';
fi
```

Comment: Your script isn't very big. It's better to include it in the answer and leave the github link for a reference. This way it will help people even if the repository will gone.